Recursive constraint default leads to incorrect inference of second argument in the absence of the first, when both have the same generic type
I'm modeling a recursive binary search tree (BST) data type using TypeScript's generic constraints. To define a default for the recursive generic variable T, without using T in the default (not allowed), I have a co-recursive 'base case' for the constraint, like so:
// Bounded polymorphism using recursive generic constraints.
type IBSTBoRecDflt<K, V> = IBSTBoRec<K, V, IBSTBoRecDflt<K, V>>;

interface IBSTBoRec<K, V, T extends IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = IBSTBoRecDflt<K, V>> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: T;
    right?: T;
}

type BSTBoRecDeflt<K, V> = BSTBoRec<K, V, BSTBoRecDeflt<K, V>>;

class BSTBoRec<K, V, T extends BSTBoRec<K, V, T> = BSTBoRecDeflt<K, V>> implements IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: T;
    right?: T;

    constructor(key: K, value: V, left?: T, right?: T) { 
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;    
    }
}

const t = new BSTBoRec(5, 'e', undefined, new BSTBoRec(8, 'h'));

The problem is that the type of the right branch (8, h) seems to be incorrectly inferred when a left branch is missing. The following error is thrown for new BSTBoRec(8, 'h') on the last line:
Argument of type 'BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRec<number, string, undefined>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 
                 'BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRec<number, string, undefined>>>'.
  Type 'BSTBoRec<number, string, undefined>' is not assignable to type 
       'BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRec<number, string, undefined>>'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'BSTBoRec<number, string, undefined>'.

The error goes away if I specify the K, V types of the (8, h) branch manually:
const t = new BSTBoRec(5, 'e', undefined, new BSTBoRec<number, string>(8, 'h'));

Why is the type of the right branch inferred incorrectly when the left branch is omitted?
Here's a playground with the code and error.

Is your question really "why"? Or are you looking to fix it?  The answer to "why" is probably "because having undefined there causes undefined to be the first inference candidate, which ends up failing and falling back to a constraint with undefined in there because the failed candidate still affects things and this may be a documented TS bug or limitation, let's go down the GitHub rabbit hole", whereas you can fix it by trying to guide inference such as this playground link. How do you want to proceed here?

Well, yeah, I’m looking to understand the “why”, along with how to work around it. I had a vague idea of the why that seems to be confirmed by your sketch. Having my vague idea confirmed by you is useful, even if I still struggle to precisely play out the inference process in my head, and connect it back to the error message. On how to fix it, the solution in your playground ties in nicely with the why-sketch. All in all, I like this answer, and it’s fine if nothing pops up from the GitHub rabbit hole.

I'll try to look to see if there's any clue in GitHub but I don't expect to find much. It's kind of a bizarre case, this sort of recursive default.

I can't say exactly why the inference is failing since I haven't stepped through the compiler code. The closest issue I found in GitHub is microsoft/TypeScript#45286, where an invalid generic type argument is inferred, even though it fails to meet the constraint. That is happening here also; it looks like that the first inference candidate for T is undefined (which is the type of left), and this affects the contextual type of new BSTBoRec(8, 'h') to include BSTBoRec<number, string, undefined>, which shouldn't ever happen.  Ideally the inference would fail here, and T would fall back to the constraint and you'd get just BTSBoRec<number, string>, but apparently that doesn't happen. I'd say this is a TypeScript bug or design limitation, but who knows if it would ever get addressed.

If I wanted to fix this, I'd probably guide inference by changing where T appears in the constructor argument types. One way to do this without changing much is:
constructor(key: K, value: V, left?: BSTBoRec<K, V, T>, right?: BSTBoRec<K, V, T>) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.left = left as T;
    this.right = right as T;
}]

which lowers the inference priority of T enough to cause it to work (except you need type assertions to assign that to T since technically it could fail to be assignable):
const t1 = new BSTBoRec(5, 'e', new BSTBoRec(8, 'h'), undefined);
// const t1: BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRecDeflt<number, string>>
const t2 = new BSTBoRec(5, 'e', undefined, new BSTBoRec(8, 'h'));
// const t2: BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRecDeflt<number, string>>

Or you could make the constructor overloaded or equivalent to being overloaded by using a union of tuple types as a rest parameter:
    constructor(key: K, value: V, ...[left, right]: [undefined, T] | [T?, T?]) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left as T;
        this.right = right as T;
    }

which makes undefined as left prefer right as the place to infer T:
const t1 = new BSTBoRec(5, 'e', new BSTBoRec(8, 'h'), undefined);
// const t1: BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRec<number, string, 
//   BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRecDeflt<number, string>> | undefined>> ???!

const t2 = new BSTBoRec(5, 'e', undefined, new BSTBoRec(8, 'h'));
// const t2: BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRec<number, string, BSTBoRecDeflt<number, string>>>

But this still has a bizarre undefined in the type that shouldn't be there, so I'd probably prefer the one at the top.

All in all I'd say that inference in the face of complicated recursive generic type argument defaults is probably prone to acting weird, so you'll have to be careful.
Playground link to code

Thanks! I discovered another workaround that's not super nice, but I thought it worth sharing. It's wrapping the constructor's arguments inside a intermediate function's tuple argument, so that, I guess, the tuple's type has to be inferred as a whole, rather than considering each argument in turn? I wonder if this trick can be transferred to the constructor, somehow, to take the intermediate function out of the picture. Here's a playground.

Interesting. Well, trying to turn it into a rest arg doesn't work, so I'm not sure how to do it.
